# How to trim more spaces of data base data using linq to sql query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am displaying matching records of data using "Contains" linq property like this.

```
a=> a.user.displayname.contains(searchtext);
```

The result are coming prefect but some times a.user.displayname having more than 2 spaces then results are not coming.How to trim database data a.user.displayname .please tell me .

displayname :

```
venkatesh    duggirala,
mic   thomson
```

morespaces in database data.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: displayngame like this -- venkat      reddy d, nagoor   meeran,

Comment: morespaces in betweeen venkat    and reddy so that not showing results.

Comment: how to trim database data.

Comment: user is a table having more properties in it.displayname is one property.i am not having firstname last name only having displayname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=> a.user.displayname.Replace(" ","").contains(searchtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace it in your query

```
select string = replace(replace(replace(' select   single       spaces',' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
```

It will replace multiple spaces into a single space in your query

Source:- [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql)

Similarly you can use in you linq too.
[Can I use LINQ to strip repeating spaces from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595583/can-i-use-linq-to-strip-repeating-spaces-from-a-string)

Or you can use Regular expression for that

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ");
```

Source:- [How do I replace multiple spaces with a single space in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206717/how-do-i-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-c)

Comment: @user3106578 I have provided a similar link in my question

Comment: can you see my above lamda expression how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the query to try and compare with the additional spaces is possible. However I do not suggest that approach because by adding complex string manipulation into a Linq query it forces the C# side to pull the full dataset, then loop through the results, and run the additional comparisons that would ignore the extra whitespace.

With more than a thousand records this will become very memory and cpu intensive, and will saddle you with some very large scalability problems in the future. I would suggest that you fix the data with a sql query, and make sure that any imports clear the extra whitespace when it moves the data over.

Comment: i am using entity framework.i am not writing any query directly a.user.displayname then getting displayname result data.